# What makes grid lines visible?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

This is more of a conceptual questions. I want to implement grid lines in an area graph. 
I am using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/11110940) as a reference. I am not able to understand in the example, where in the code exactly are the grid lines being drawn so that I can implement those in my area graph. I am using following code to plot the axis.

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left")
          .ticks(4,".1s")
          .tickSize(10, 0);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(numberOfDays)
          .tickSize(10, 0);

        vis.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);
        vis.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + HEIGHT + ")")
          .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: The grid lines usually are just the axis ticks. If you want more control, you should implement them separately.

Answer (score 4):

From the example shown I have implemented this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6p3bvqrL/

You can see that the following create the lines :

```
 .innerTickSize()
 .outerTickSize()
```

Examples :

https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes

http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6579467

Comment: This does the job for me. But one more related question. Can I filter these tick lines. Basically I have given .ticks(4,".1s") . Which means it is only plotting 4 ticks(text). But it is still plotting all the tick lines on its own. How can I have only 4 as the number of tick lines(grid lines)

Comment: Set up an example of what you have already in JSFiddle and ill take a look

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but following what @Robert said, if you want to have more control over your gridlines, you can append them separately.

First, set the CSS:

```
.axis .grid-line{
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke-opacity: .2;
}
```

Then, after calling the axes:

```
d3.selectAll("g.x-axis g.tick") 
        .append("line")
        .classed("grid-line", true)
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", 0)
        .attr("y2", - (height - 2 * margin));

d3.selectAll("g.y-axis g.tick")
        .append("line")
        .classed("grid-line", true)
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", (width - 2 * margin)) 
        .attr("y2", 0);
```

Changing `width`, `length` and `margin` accordingly, of course.

You can find more information in Zhu's book: http://nickqizhu.github.io/d3-cookbook/

PS: I'm showing this alternative but, normally, when I create a dataviz, I do the way described by thatOneGuy.